# AngularJS Directive into React App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, angularjs-directive

We are looking at writing a new app using React but will need some existing Angular Directive that are specific for our business, for example a modified Angular Date Picker for example. There are many components so we won't be able to rewrite them all.

I am wondering if anyone has experience or knows the effort or feasibility of this?

The only article I've managed to find on this so far has been. Most resources I find mention going the other way from an Angular App with added React. http://softeng.oicr.on.ca/chang_wang/2017/04/17/Using-AngularJS-components-directives-in-React/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a library called [angular2react](https://github.com/coatue-oss/angular2react) that makes possible reuse angularjs code inside react components. You can see if it fits your needs. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple demo app showcasing how to achieve it: [react-angularjs-bridge](https://github.com/katrotz/react-angularjs-bridge)

The basic steps are as follows:

1. Create a react component that is going to host the angular component in the DOM. This component should always render a simple html element (eg. a `HTMLDivElement`) so that react does not get confused when reconciling the virtual DOM with the real DOM.
2. After the react component was mounted `componentDidMount`, create a shadow root under the rendered `HTMLDivElement` and initialise the angular application under it. This will ensure that the angularJS component is encapsulated and is not affected by the react application and vice-versa

Click [here](https://react-angularjs-bridge.herokuapp.com/) for a demo. Check how the react application styles do not impact the styles of the angular component.

Answer (score 0):

Independently of Angular, `ref` is a way to go: it gives to access to an underlying DOM node and the ability to manipulate the DOM *inside* that node in any way you like, including AngularJS. Your changes will stay - at least until react clears the component altogether.

You can create a ref in react by

```
<divOrAnyOtherDom ref={((el) => {this._elem=el;}).bind(this)}></...
```

(for the full description and alternate ways to the same end see here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)

Anyway, as you now have a DOM node, you can start working with it, i.e. adding angular to the mix inside `componentDidMount`. Sadly, this is not really obvious - here's a way that has worked for me in the past (`moduleName` needs to be a module you have put in place already with your logic):

```
let baseElement = angular.element(this._elem);
let templateElement = angular.element(templateSource);
angular.injector([ 'ng', moduleName ]).invoke(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    let cmp = $compile(templateElement);
    scpe = $rootScope.$new(false);
    scpe.varname = whateverYouHave; # point is: you can set scope variables
    cmp(scpe);
    baseElement.append(templateElement);
    scpe.$digest();
});
```

Now you have angular inside the DOM node react gave you.

(I've taken this from a slightly different integration: Vaadin to AngularJS, but the principle is the same: Vaadin, just like react, gives you a DOM node. When you're interested in the full code: https://github.com/akquinet/vaangular/blob/master/vaangular/src/main/resources/de/akquinet/engineering/vaadin/vaangular/angular/NgTemplate.js)

Plus: For any callbacks from the angular component, you'll likely have to use `setState` et al.